# Customizing input validation in swagger ui

Tags: validation, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

We are exposing swagger-ui from our webserver using the Swashbuckle package working on top of Asp.Net Core. We are hitting an input validation issue for our Guid input fields.

The GUIDs we are pasting in, which are read from other parts of the system, are formatted as *deb83f8a3edc4b78a2ece3321f81b58b*, note the missing dashes. The input validation rejects this as it expects dashes in the format (so it accepts *deb83f8a-3edc-4b78-a2ec-e3321f81b58b*).

The swagger document that we serve has the parameter as type: string and format: uuid. It calls to some internal *validationGuid* call that have a reg-ex that forces the dashes. From the browser Console it seems like it is looking for a component called JsonSchema_string_uuid but is not finding it.

So my question is how can I extend swagger-ui to override the validation of specific parameter type/formats?

UPDATE:
I was made aware of the RFC that specifies a UUID as containing dashes and a workaround. However, I'm still interested in learning about ways to customize the validation of both custom formats and specifically uuid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the OpenAPI Specification and JSON Schema do not currently define `format: uuid`, [RFC 4122](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122#section-3) defines UUID as containing dashes, and [some](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/845#issuecomment-378139730) [comments](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/607#issuecomment-200452003) in the OpenAPI repository suggest that `format: uuid` is supposed to follow RFC 4122. This means your example without dashes is most likely not `format: uuid`.

Consider replacing `format: uuid` with `pattern: '^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$`'.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know about the RFC. I'll note the ability to specify the specific pattern but I'm still interested in providing custom validation if you have any info on this.

Comment: I _think_ the only way is to fork & build your own version, because [`validateGuid`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/core/utils.js#L446) is part of the "core" functions. That said, I'd suggest asking in the [Swagger UI repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/new/choose) so that you can get an answer directly from Swagger UI devs.

Comment: Thanks @Helen, I've gone with your pattern suggestion and might post a question on the SwaggerUI repo for their thoughts